# Error in Weka: error in opening zip file

Tags: weka

I am trying to use Weka 3.8 and 3.9 (tried both versions in Mac and Windows) but I can't seem to install any additional packages. It always gives the error: error in opening zip file.

```
java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:219)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:149)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:163)
at weka.core.packageManagement.DefaultPackageManager.getPackageArchiveInfo(DefaultPackageManager.java:354)
at weka.core.packageManagement.DefaultPackageManager.installPackageFromArchive(DefaultPackageManager.java:501)
at weka.core.packageManagement.DefaultPackageManager.installPackageFromURL(DefaultPackageManager.java:769)
at weka.core.packageManagement.DefaultPackageManager.installPackageFromRepository(DefaultPackageManager.java:753)
at weka.core.WekaPackageManager.installPackageFromRepository(WekaPackageManager.java:1938)
at weka.gui.PackageManager$InstallTask.doInBackground(PackageManager.java:1308)
at weka.gui.PackageManager$InstallTask.doInBackground(PackageManager.java:863)
at javax.swing.SwingWorker$1.call(SwingWorker.java:295)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at javax.swing.SwingWorker.run(SwingWorker.java:334)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: I can confirm Ramos V's answer works well, but is there a way to automatically download that long list of files? As to why the error happens, it seems the links are semi-broken. It tells you where the new resource is located. Sourceforge returns an HTML file instead of the ZIP. As an example, the page says "302 Found ... The resource was found at https://superb-sea2.dl.sourceforge.net/project/weka/weka-packages/wekaDeeplearning4j1.0.2.zip ...
you should be redirected automatically." If you want help the authors to hack/fix the links, you can add code that redirects to the link given.

Answer (score 6):

I have been facing the same problem in both Windows and Mac. What worked for me was to download the packages I was interested in at https://sourceforge.net/projects/weka/files/weka-packages/
After the download, open your package manager in weka and in Unofficial select File/Url and choose the downloaded package file. After this, you just have to close and open weka again and your packages should be available.
Hope this helps!
V.

Comment: which file should I choose ? the zip file or the jar file after unzipping the file?